# Легкая CMS с простым написанием компонентов

Tags: php, cms

Существуют ли какие-нибудь "простейшие" CMS, к которым легко дописать необходимые фичи?
Одно время занимался Joomla, но, если честно, не хватило упорства (и знаний тогда) разобраться во всем движке.

Меня интересует в первую очередь какой-нибудь движек, с простеньким наботром компонентов, типа Регистрация, добавление Статей и т.д.

P.S. Движок для сайта типа "визитка", сайта о компании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModX